# automating entering username and password on terminal using bash

Tags: shell-script, terminal, openvpn, authentication

Actually, the command I'm running is

```
sudo openvpn nl-free-01.protonvpn.com.udp.ovpn
```

So this asks for username and password every time I run the command

```
Enter Auth Username:
Enter Auth Password:
```

I want to automate this using bash script...
Is it possible?

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/386305/117549 ?

Answer (score 0):

create a new file besides the ovpn file, e.g. `pass.txt`, write the username in the first line and the password in the second line (don't forget the extra newline at the end of the file). Then extend your config-file with `auth-user-pass pass.txt`.

BTW: if you're running a recent distribution, you can place the config- and pass.txt-file under `/etc/openvpn` (if necessary like on fedora in the subdirectory `/etc/openvpn/client` and control it with `systemd start openvpn@nl-free-01.protonvpn.com.udp.service` (or `systemd start openvpn-client@nl-free-01.protonvpn.com.udp.service` on fedora). To have it automatically enabled, use `enable --now` instead of `start`. You can check the status with `systemctl status`

source: https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=11342#p25419